# iOS 7+ server verified inapp purchasing sending many receipts

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am trying to get the new inapp purchasing API (ios 7+) to work and I see that the receipt data is so much larger when I read receipts in this way:

```
        NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
        NSData *receiptData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
```

I am doing this inside of:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

So what I noticed is I send the receipt to
"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";
And the data I'm sending is much larger than transaction.transactionReceipt.

In fact, the apple response seems to have **dozens** of receipts in the "in_app" array.  **Is this normal?** I have finished these transactions yet there is so many receipts in the unified receipt. Is that right? Would my big spenders (those who buy thousands of IAPs) be sending huge receipts with thousands of transactions in them?

Also what is SKReceiptRefreshRequest for?

Update! I found out that in a live environment, all consumable receipts are removed after they calling finishTransaction. On the sandbox environment this is not the case, and it just keeps them, so the number of receipts can get into the hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

iOS7 introduced many IAP changes. Amongst those:
1) receipts are stored in the app bundle (yes, plural on receipts)
2) whether a particular receipt persists in the bundle depends on the kind of product. Eg, I think receipts for consumables don't get persisted

What kind of products do you have?

Look up the API for the receipt refresh. Sometimes the receipt is not in the bundle, and you can refresh it. The user gets prompted for apple id/password so it can be annoying for the user if/when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Yes, this is normal

Apply sends you a bunch of all receipts. You have to figure out your own what to do with these. That's because even if the transaction is finished you might need the receipt to handle the content of the purchase.